# group by a key and get the entire object based on a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, count

```
Input: [{
    "SRN": "SN18000023",
    "EventDate": "7/15/2020",
    "PatientCount": "31",
    "ProductType": "ProxiDiagnost N90",
    "KeyMarket": "NORTH AMERICA"
  },
   {
    "SRN": "SN18000023",
    "EventDate": "7/15/2020",
    "PatientCount": "31",
    "ProductType": "ProxiDiagnost N90",
    "KeyMarket": "NORTH AMERICA"
  }]
```

Here i am trying to group by SRN and get the PatientCount using loadash as shown below

```
const patientGridData =loadash(filteredKeyValue).groupBy('SRN')
    .map((objs, key) => ({
        'SRN': key,  
        "ProductType":objs["ProductType"],  
        'count': loadash.sumBy(objs, item => Number(item.PatientCount))
    }))
```

know i am getting the output has

```
[
    {
        "SRN": "SN18000023",
        "count": 62
    }]
```

but i  want all the key values along with the count as shown below

```
 [
        {
            "SRN": "SN18000023",
            "count": 200,
      "ProductType": "ProxiDiagnost N90",
        "KeyMarket": "NORTH AMERICA"
        }]
```

please suggest a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the property from the first index.

```js
const
    filteredKeyValue = [{ SRN: "SN18000023", EventDate: "7/15/2020", PatientCount: "31", ProductType: "ProxiDiagnost N90", KeyMarket: "NORTH AMERICA" }, { SRN: "SN18000023", EventDate: "7/15/2020", PatientCount: "31", ProductType: "ProxiDiagnost N90", KeyMarket: "NORTH AMERICA" }],
    patientGridData = _(filteredKeyValue)
        .groupBy('SRN')
        .map((objs, key) => ({
            SRN: key,
            ProductType: objs[0].ProductType,
            KeyMarket: objs[0].KeyMarket,
            count: _.sumBy(objs, item => Number(item.PatientCount))
        }));

console.log(patientGridData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```